# Java jetty external address

Tags: java, web, jetty

I want my server (jetty) to be accessed over the network at a specific address.
How can I configure jetty server to use external address, as an example: my_address_name.org or as something else.

because by default:

```
server = new Server(port);
        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

        context.setResourceBase(app_path);
        context.setDescriptor(app_path + "WEB-INF/web.xml");

        context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
                new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebXmlConfiguration(),
                new WebInfConfiguration(), new TagLibConfiguration(),
                new PlusConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
                new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration() });

        context.setContextPath(context_path);
        context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        server.setHandler(context);

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join(); ...
```

it runs on localhost...

Answer (score 0):

This example will bind to specific IP and listen on port 9090:

```
Connector con = new SelectChannelConnector();
con.setHost("192.168.1.20");
con.setPort(9090);
server.addConnector(con);
```

(If I remember well Jetty always binds by default to all IP's (0.0.0.0)).